# AWS API-Gateway is adding an AWSELB Cookie. Some of the time

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to connect to a REST API via the AWS API Gateway. The REST API requires authentication and uses a session cookie. The client that sends the request to the API Gateway will include the session cookie in the request. I need the cookie to be included when the API Gateway connects to the REST API. Most of the time this works, however, some of the time the session cookie appears to be corrupted by having an AWSELB cookie appended to it.

I have created a resource in the API Gateway and a GET method that points at the REST API. In the GET method configuration, the Method Request is configured to read the "Cookie" header. The Integration Request is configured to pass the contents of the incoming Cookie header to the REST API, still as a Cookie. I believe this configuration should read the cookie the client sends and include it in the request to the REST API. The client is only sending 1 cookie.

Most of the time this works and the REST API recognises the cookie and responds as expected.  However, sometimes it does not work. The REST API reacts as though the user is not authenticated - as if the cookie is not there or if the value in the cookie is wrong (I think this is the problem).

When I look at the contents of the cookies that the REST API receives (using PHP's $_COOKIE) for a successful request I see the following :

```
{"SESS":"1KDZI9w1-Gc"}
```

which looks right to me and seems to work.

On those occasions where the REST API rejects the request (roughly 1 in 10) the cookies are reported like this:

```
{"SESS":"1KDZI9w1-Gc, AWSELB=69436F3F12017A3019CD7D4088C8FE7CC9981879EC03298C21B00D11E135F6C2D5BB6EB9EF4CA2F57491F67AE917BF7D76679C66E3785516822E528C0314730437CFEBF999"}
```

It looks like another cookie, the AWS Elastic Load Balancer cookie, AWSELB, has been appended to the end of the session cookie. The REST API is behind an ELB. I have session stickiness turned off on the ELB.

I don't know why the AWSELB cookie is being added, the client's request to the API Gateway does not include the cookie.

If the API-Gateway or other component is adding the AWSELB cookie then that shouldn't really be a problem as long as it is being added in the right way. It should be a separate cookie, not appended to the value of the session cookie.

If I look at the headers the REST API receives when the AWSELB cookie is present, the Cookie header looks like this:

```
"SESS=1KDZI9w1-Gc, AWSELB=69436F3F12017A3019CD7D4088C8FE7CC9981879EC03298C21B00D11E135F6C2D5BB6EB9EF4CA2F57491F67AE917BF7D76679C66E3785516822E528C0314730437CFEBF999"
```

When multiple cookies are being sent I think they should be separated by a semi-colon ";" not a comma "," as appears to be happening.

Can anyone advise on how I might solve this? I would like to either stop the AWSELB cookie being included or make sure it is included in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API Gateway recently deployed a fix to this issue. Please refer to the forums post [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=690699).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I will give it a try.